# struts 2 dojo datepicker not working in iterator tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, datepicker, dojo

I have a jsp page where i show the experience of a employee which contains the following fields -company name,start date,end date,reason for quit.
every thing is fine at time of retrieval but when i try to update start date or end date from jsp page i get null values at action class but other parameter are updated.  this problem is with chrome only .it works fine for ie 8.
**Struts 2 dojo date picker values sends null value to action class when save.**

//pojo

```
public class Experience {


private int emp_id;
private String Company_Name;
private Date Start_Date;
private Date End_Date;
private String Reason_For_Exit;
private String Last_Drawn_Compensation;
//getter and setter
}
```

//action class

```
public class ExperienceAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Experience> list = new ArrayList<Experience>();
    //getter and setter and other properties
}
```

//jsp page

```
<s:iterator value="list" var="e" status="cnt">
<tr>
<td style="padding-top: 2px;"> Company Name</td>
<td><s:textfield type="text"  name="list\[{#cnt.index}\].Company_Name" /></td>
<td> Start Date  </td>
<td><sx:datetimepicker  name="list{#cnt.index}\].Start_Date" />      </td>
<td>End Date</td>
<td ><sx:datetimepicker  name="list\[%{#cnt.index}\].End_Date" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Tenure</td>
<td><!--other element--></td></s:iterator>
```

[image: 1]

i am able to retrieve values from database and retrive and  display them on ui but i am not able to send these values back to action class

[image: 2]

Comment: To send values back you need to create an action that will handle POST requests with the data you want to send back. Note, that dojo plugin is deprecated and the data might be lost before you send it, so you should check if you can receive it or not.

Comment: but how it work with ie8.

Comment: Any alternative for S2 dojo plugin.